# Put JSON in a getter and setter

Tags: java, android, json, getter-setter

My problem is I can't or I don't know how to retrieve my JSON data in the class `valeur` which is the class that contains the setter and getter of my variables.

I have a class which displays my variables which is `AfficheurListView`.

I want just parsing my JSON and the result of this needs to be in the getter and setter of the class value to be displayed on the method `onCreate` of my class `AfficheurListView`.

I know how use it in the try/catch but I don't want to show my variable mpx in the try/catch

`AfficheurListView.java`

```
public class AfficheurListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String json_string2;
    String json_string;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    TextView textView;
    String mpx,rds,al,ar,frequence,pilots,id,id_SIGFOX,timestamps,rf;
    Valeurs valeurss=new Valeurs( mpx,rds,al,ar,frequence,pilots,id,id_SIGFOX,timestamps,rf);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_listview_layout);

    json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
    json_string2=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_Mpx");
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    textView.setText(valeurss.getMpx()); //display the variable mpx of the getter


    try {
       String mpx,rds,al,ar,frequence,pilots,id,id_SIGFOX,timestamps,rf;
        jObj = new JSONObject(json_string);
        mpx=  jObj.getString("MPX");
        rds =jObj.getString("RDS");
        rf=jObj.getString("RF");
        frequence =jObj.getString("Frequence");
        timestamps=jObj.getString("timestamp");
        id= jObj.getString("id");
        id_SIGFOX= jObj.getString("id_SIGFOX");
        pilots= jObj.getString("PILOT");
        al= jObj.getString("a_l");
        ar= jObj.getString("a_r");

       Valeurs valeurs=new Valeurs(mpx,rds,al,ar,frequence,pilots,id,timestamps,id_SIGFOX,rf);
        valeurss=valeurs;



    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

`Valeurs.java`

```
public class Valeurs{


private String mpx,rds,al,ar,pilots,frequence,id,timestamps,id_SIGFOX,rf;
    public Valeurs(String mpx, String rds, String al, String ar, String pilots, String frequence, String id, String timestamps, String id_SIGFOX, String rf)

    {
        this.setMpx(mpx);
        this.setRds(rds);
        this.setAl(al);
        this.setAr(ar);
        this.setPilots(pilots);
        this.setFrequence(frequence);
        this.setId(id);
        this.setTimestamps(timestamps);
        this.setId_SIGFOX(id_SIGFOX);
        this.setRf(rf);


    }




public String getMpx() {
    return mpx;
}

public void setMpx(String mpx) {
    this.mpx = mpx;
}

public String getRds() {
    return rds;
}

public void setRds(String rds) {
    this.rds = rds;
}

public String getAl() {
    return al;
}

public void setAl(String al) {
    this.al = al;
}

public String getAr() {
    return ar;
}

public void setAr(String ar) {
    this.ar = ar;
}

public String getPilots() {
    return pilots;
}

public void setPilots(String pilots) {
    this.pilots = pilots;
}

public String getFrequence() {
    return frequence;
}

public void setFrequence(String frequence) {
    this.frequence = frequence;
}

public String getTimestamps() {
    return timestamps;
}

public void setTimestamps(String timestamps) {
    this.timestamps = timestamps;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId_SIGFOX() {
    return id_SIGFOX;
}

public void setId_SIGFOX(String id_SIGFOX) {
    this.id_SIGFOX = id_SIGFOX;
}

public String getRf() {
    return rf;
}

public void setRf(String rf) {
    this.rf = rf;
}
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your issue & you should at least remove commented code from your example.

Comment: i'm french sorry for that i don't have again a good english i will remove and commente this ( and i want just display my variable mpx of my getter of the class valeurs on the textView )

Comment: If I properly understood your issue : you want to move the json parsing from AfficheurListView to Valeurs ?
Why not having a static method Valeurs::fromJson(String json) that returns a Valeurs instance which parsed the json itself ?

Comment: I'm starting on android studio can u show me a example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I highly recommend you to use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to convert String to your Java object (in this case your class Valeurs.java) and Java object to String, it's called **serialization and deserialization**.

Then, in *try* statement in AfficheurListView.java, edit to:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
Valeurs valeurs = gson.fromJson(json_string, Valeurs.class);
```

Now, you can get mpx with:

```
valeurs.getMpx();
```

**Note:** Field name must to match with your JSON fields.

**Note 2:** Do not use plural for class name (example: Valeurs -> Valeur).

Hope it helps you!

**EDIT:** you need to implement something like that:

```
public class AfficheurListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String json_string2;
    String json_string;

    TextView textView;
    String mpx, rds, al, ar, frequence, pilots, id, id_SIGFOX, timestamps, rf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_listview_layout);

        json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        json_string2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_Mpx");

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        try {
            // Json Object {}
            /* Useless, because you use GSON instead of this
            String mpx, rds, al, ar, frequence, pilots, id, id_SIGFOX, timestamps, rf;
            jObj = new JSONObject(json_string);
            mpx = jObj.getString("MPX");
            rds = jObj.getString("RDS");
            rf = jObj.getString("RF");
            frequence = jObj.getString("Frequence");
            timestamps = jObj.getString("timestamp");
            id = jObj.getString("id");
            id_SIGFOX = jObj.getString("id_SIGFOX");
            pilots = jObj.getString("PILOT");
            al = jObj.getString("a_l");
            ar = jObj.getString("a_r");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Valeurs valeurs = new Valeurs(mpx, rds, al, ar, frequence, pilots, id, timestamps, id_SIGFOX, rf);*/
            // So, now 'valeurs' and 'valeurs2' are
            Valeurs valeurs = gson.fromJson(json_string, Valeurs.class);
            Valeurs valeurs2 = gson.fromJson(json_string2, Valeurs.class);

            // if your program is here, then you have no parsing error, so set your textView
            textView.setText(valeurs2.getMpx());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // You have an error
            textView.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, So i need to create a class gson ? for convert my String to my Java Object?? so witth gson i will have 3 class ? AfficheurLisView, Valeur,and Gson?

Comment: No, you can easily implement GSON to your project with [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) or download sources on [github](https://github.com/google/gson). So, you have GSON library and your classes AfficheurLisView, Valeur. Just edit your try/catch statement as described and it's done.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to implement GSON in your case